# How to run this function properly?

Tags: python-3.x, list, for-loop, object

I wrote a function which accepts string and returns list of pairs of two character.If the string has odd number of character then it returns last character with _ in pair.

```
def split_pairs(a):
    if a == '':
        return list(a)
    x = list(a)
    if len(x) == 2:
        return [f'{a}']
    if len(x) % 2 != 0:
        x.append('_')
    b = x[:]
    s = ''
    for i in x[1:]:
        if len(x[:x.index(i)]) % 2 == 0:
            b.insert(b.index(i), ',')
    lst = s.join(b)
    z = lst.split(',')
    return z


print(split_pairs("sam"))
print(split_pairs("sa"))
print(split_pairs("samip"))
print(split_pairs("ss"))
print(split_pairs("sss"))
print(split_pairs("ssss"))
```

The function works fine with above three words "sam", "sa", "samip".But it doesn't work with other four.
The outputs are:

**['sa', 'mi', 'p_']**

**['ss']**

**['', '', 'sss_']**

**['', '', '', 'ssss']**

**['', '', '', 'sa', 'masasds_']**

The problem is while inserting the value in b the index of i which refers to **s** in the case of multiple s and i think all the **s** are same so instead of inserting in index of the middle **s** or the expected **s** it puts the index of first **s**.

Please explain what is happening in the function and how can the function run properly.If my above guess is close to actually problem or close to the problem please tell me how to treat **s** at different place differently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this will solve your problem

```
def split_pairs(b):
    if b == '' or len(b) == 2 :
        return [b]
    if len(b) % 2 != 0:
        b+='_'
    return [b[i]+b[i+1] for i in range(0,len(b),2)]
    


print(split_pairs("sam"))
print(split_pairs("sa"))
print(split_pairs("samip"))
print(split_pairs("ss"))
print(split_pairs("sss"))
print(split_pairs("ssss"))
```

Comment: Thanks dude but do we need ```x = list(a)``` and ```b = a```.Just asking.

Comment: Not necessary @SamipKarki